# Validate username and password in phpmyAdmin

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to validate a database (phpMyadmin) using Username and Password. I need to search in all the tables (25 tables in my database) for checking if the given username and password are present (Authentication) or not. Can anyone provide the query to search entire table using the given username and password?

Below is my code

```
public class Dbclass {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    ResultSetMetaData metaData = null;
    String DB_URL="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String USER="java";
    String PASS="redhat";
    String username;
    String password;
    ResultSet rs;
    public ResultSet dbConnection(String query)
    {

        //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            try {
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

                //STEP 4: Execute a query
                System.out.println("Creating statement...");
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

                //sql = "SELECT username,password FROM Employees";
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                while(rs.next()){
                    //Retrieve by column name
                    username  = rs.getString("user_name");
                    password = rs.getString("password");

                    //Display values
                    System.out.print("User_name: " + username);
                    System.out.print(",Password: " + password);
                }
                Authentication obj=new Authentication();
                obj.userLogin(username,password);

                //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
                //rs.close();
                //return rs;
                stmt.close();
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                //TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException es) {
            //TODO Auto-generated catch block
            es.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            //finally block used to close resources
            try{
                if(conn!=null){
                    conn.close();
                }
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
        }//end try
        return rs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far, code-wise..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for a where clause. Something like below.

> SELECT username,password FROM Employees where username='usernm' and password='pwd'

If required, you can add UNION to merge more such queries, but not recommended due to performance issues.